# shortcut to Files opens LibreOffice

Tags: pantheon-files, keyboard-shortcuts

For one login, the keyboard shortcut *Command+E* flashes a *LibreOffice* window (I've installed it) instead of opening *Files*.
But for another login, the shortcut opens *Files* OK.
As far as I can tell, the shortcut has been defined the same way for both logins ... but there's obviously a difference ... which I can not pinned down: any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what system keyboard shortcuts are set up on your system by looking in System Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts. On my system `<Super>E` launches a new Files window because I have a custom shortcut set up which runs `io.elementary.files -n ~`.  Variable results from the same action suggests a race between two processes both responding to the same shortcut.

Comment: I did that and it works ... still, there's a shortcut doing this in the *Applications* shortcuts section that does exactly that and that used to work. I don't know what's launched but I see a LibreOffice logo flashing.
Thanks anyway the shortcut is working even though not the way it should.